# What happened to Magane at the end of the anime?

Tags: re-creators

During the *Re:Creators* anime series, most of the creations from the other worlds ended up:

> dying, creating a new world (Altair & Setsuna), returning to their original fictional worlds, or staying in the creators' world (Meteora).

What happened with Magane?

> Since she didn't die or return to her original world, could one conclude that she also decided to stay in the world of the creators, albeit without any powers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Magane...**

> **...went to a foreign country and stays in the world of the creators as a normal human.**

According to both [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re:CREATORS#%E7%84%A1%E6%89%80%E5%B1%9E) and [Pixiv Dictionary (Japanese)](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E7%AF%89%E5%9F%8E%E9%99%A2%E7%9C%9F%E9%8D%B3#h3_1):

> その後はフェスの顛末を見届けることなく会場を後にし、国外へ旅立つ。
>  ほかの被造物とは異なりフェス後の描写はないが、**広江礼威によれば彼女もメテオラと同様に能力を失うという**。
>
>  After that, she left the venue without seeing the end of the Elimination Chamber Festival and went on a journey to a foreign country.
>  Unlike the other creations, there is no scene of what happens after the festival, but **according to Rei Hiroe, she loses her powers just like Meteora**.

and

> 最終話(22話)で、メテオラの展開したゲートで元の物語世界へ戻った描写はない。
>  これによって、数少ない被造物で現実世界に残ったメンバーとなった。
>
>  ただし、**広江礼威氏曰く「彼女はいずれメテオラと同じく能力を無くす。つまり、普通の人間になる」とのこと**。
>
>  In the last episode (episode 22), there is no scene of her returning to her original fictional world through the gate deployed by Meteora.
>  This made her one of the few creations who remained in the real world.
>
>  However, **according to Rei Hiroe, "She eventually loses her abilities just like Meteora. In other words, she becomes a normal human being."**

*(Unfortunately, I couldn't find the original source for Rei Hiroe's statement)*